# HDMI output does not fill full 800x480 TFT display

Tags: hdmi, pi-zero-w, display, raspbian-lite, framebuffer

I have a Raspberry Pi running Raspberry Pi OS Lite (CLI only). The Pi is attached over HDMI, via an [adapter](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2219), to a [7.0 inch 800x480 TFT display](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2354) from Adafruit. When I boot up the CLI, the console only occupies about 80% of the screen. There is a black area (about an inch wide) at the right of the screen. When I run a GUI app via Pygame on the framebuffer (with `pygame.display.set_mode((pygame.display.Info().current_w, pygame.display.Info().current_h))`), I have the same issue. How do I get rid of this black border?

I have tried to follow some guides, but I can't find the appropriate directions because 5:3 is not a standard aspect ratio for a screen.

Comment: there's a 15:9 (which is exactly 5:3, not sure why they haven't reduced that ratio in the documentation) ... oh, and if you look at some [documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md) search for "custom mode" - you'll see the example is **exactly** what you want - curiously, the board apparently ships with a 800x480 EDID ... so, it should just work

Comment: See https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/hdmi-config.md